# How can I conditionally sum a set of columns in Excel with a VB Script or Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I write a script I can bind to a button in an  excel file to scan a column in the sheet (red) and filter each value then check another column (blue) then filtering it by each of those values, and then sum other columns (green) based on that criteria?
[image: Data arrangement]

This data file will have a few thousand rows.  There is no master list of possible Transaction Descriptions to check against.  Expected output would leave non calculated fields the same. Transaction code, retailer number, transaction date would equal today, document number doesn't matter, product code doesn't matter, Cust Product Code is second column we will filter by, and all remaining columns would need to be added together provided the first and second filters match.  The fields that say "sign" showing either blank or a 1 indicate if the value next to it is positive or negative. End result would look like this:
[image: output]

Comment: Have you looked into the SUMIFS() function? It may be possible without vba.

Comment: yeah, look into sumifs and pivot tables. shouldn't need vba.

Comment: try also using AutoFilter so you can display only the data you're interested in

Comment: If you still need a script for this, use macro recorder when applying the solutions suggested (autofilter, sumifs or pivot tables)

Comment: I have decided to pursue the processing of this data in sql.  This is to be an unattended batch file that will process data comping in and produce an output file.  The data and contents will be different every week, so macros and pivot tables won't work for me.  I think perhaps a sql query might be better suited to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to pursue the processing of this data in sql.  This is to be an unattended batch file that will process data comping in and produce an output file.  The data and contents will be different every week, so macros and pivot tables won't work for me.  I think perhaps a sql query might be better suited to accomplish my goal.